# Understanding maximums in MLE proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, statistics

[image]

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the second equality in the proof, namely $ \max_{\eta = g(\theta)} L(\eta) = \max_{\eta} L(g^{-1}(\eta))$.

So as far as I understand, $\hat{\theta}$ maximizes the function $L(\theta)$ and we are looking for a value of $\eta = g(\theta)$ that maximizes $L$.

I accept the first equality - we're looking for $\max L(g(\theta))$ which is the same as finding the max of $L(\eta)$ for values $\eta = g(\theta)$. Just a simple relabeling (please correct me if I'm wrong).

What I don't get is where the next step comes from. The subscript simply says $\eta$ and it's not clear to me what values of $\eta$ we're looking at. It's also not clear to me how we were able to replace $\eta$ with $g^{-1}(\eta)$.

If $g$ is a function $ \Omega \to \Sigma$ then $\theta \in \Omega$ and $g(\theta) = \eta \in \Sigma$. So it looks to me that we jumped from considering values in the codomain $\Sigma$ that maximize $L$ to values $g^{-1}(\eta) \in \Omega$ in the domain? Why are these maximums equal?

Where is the gap in my understanding?

Comment: interesting question ... hope you get an answer!

Comment: Potential answer: $g$ is a one to one function on the parameter space, hence every possible parameter can be written in the form $g(\theta)$ which is why the equality holds (maximizing $L(\eta)$ for values of $\eta$ is the same as maximizing $L(g^{-1}(\eta))$ for values of $\eta$)

Comment: If $g$ is one-to-one then, for every possible $\theta$ in its parameter space, there is exactly one $\eta$ in the transformed parameter space. For some specific $\theta$ you have an $\eta = g(\theta)$  and you can return with $\theta=g^{-1}(\eta)$: the likelihood of that $\eta$ in its parameter space is the same as the likelihood of that $\theta$.  With this equality, the $\theta$ with maximum likelihood corresponds to the $\eta$ with maximum likelihood.